# Material design css fails if input type is email

Tags: html, css, material-design

I have found a few code pens that have material design examples for forms.  I found a few that have the same issue.

If `input` type is set to `"text"` or `"password"` they work fine, but they fail if set to `"email"`.  Is there a way to fix this?  I have tried making the css rules specifically target `input[type=email]`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBgeqR

http://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/WGKmKP?editors=1100

Comment: It's working for me in Firefox 49 and Chrome 54. Which browser specifically are you having a problem with?

Comment: Oops, I see what you mean. The form validation is messing it up.

Comment: 0_o i have only tried Version 54.0.2840.99 m ... oh i guess i should mention those codepens have inputs with type="text" change to type="email" if you want to see it fail.

Comment: The problem is it's not possible to determine if an input has an empty value in CSS. Javascript needs to be involved for these demos to work 100%.

Comment: I think one of those code pens only uses css and it seems to work pretty well, except if its type="email"

Comment: Hence 100%, not 80%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the material design doesn't support HTML5 inputs like `email`.

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/853

From the answer: *"For now, text fields are exactly that: text fields."*